# How to deploy Drools workbench(version 6.3.0 Final) to Tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat, drools, drools-guvnor

I feel so despairing!It is so hard to deploy drools workbench!
At first I only find a war package,so i simply use it as Activiti 5.0. However, as you see, it fails.Then I find that it has to do something as the User guide said, and I do it, and it still change nothing.
I cost so much time to find jars (why does the developer to support them in downloads?) and create files, and it still not work.I do not know why as I had everything as the guide tells me.
Is there someone can help me?
each time I deploy .war in manager Page,I will get this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8GC5.jpg)
but when I deploy other .war I will not get this problem.

Answer (score 1):

this guide is for kieServer (kie-server-7.37.0.Final-ee8) and drools workbench or bussiness central (business-central-7.35.0.Final-wildfly14) and wildFly 14.0.1 not tomcat.

kindly use these versions only otherwise it won't work.

```
Steps

1) Extract WildFly zip.

2) copy Kie-drools-wb.zip and kie-server.zip into directory-> wildfly-14.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments.

3) Increase its java space goto wildfly-14.0.1.Final/ bin. 
open standalone.conf. replace JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=512M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"  with  JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=512M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

4)   Add Application user run command -> ./add-user.sh -a -u kieserver -p kieserver -ro admin,kie-server,rest-all,kiemgmt

5) Add Management user run command -> ./add-user.sh 
name- kieserver
password- kieserver
role- admin
slave host controller- yes 

6) run server using command ->  ./standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full.xml -Dorg.kie.server.user=kieserver -Dorg.kie.server.pwd=kieserver -Dorg.kie.server.controller.user=kieserver -Dorg.kie.server.controller.pwd=kieserver -Dorg.kie.server.location=http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server -Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb/rest/controller -Dorg.kie.server.id=wildfly-kieserver &

7) when you see "task finished successfully." in logs go to url to open drools workbench -> http://localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb/
 enter user- kieserver and password- kieserver
if home page after login is not open. reload or login again

8) open kieser server -> http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers
check that page has <response type="SUCCESS" msg="List of created containers">

9) check that kie server is connected to workbench-> 
 a) go to menu-> under deploy you have Excecution servers(click).
 b) In the remote-server you should have -> wildfly-kieserver@localhost

10) now you have up and running drools connected with kie server
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to deploy workbench and server some weeks ago and I write a step-by-step guide based on a blog post. I found deploying on wildfly easier than tomcat. Try this:

Setup for KIE Workbench and KIE Server

> Environment: Windows 7
>
> Java version:             JDK 8.0
>
> Application server:   Wildfly8.2.0.Final
>
> Versioning control:        Git

Steps used from [here](http://mswiderski.blogspot.ro/2015/10/installing-kie-server-and-workbench-on.html)

1) Download Wildfly distribution from wildfly website
   Choose version 8.2.0.Final with description Java EE7 Full & Web Distribution
   Unpack the archive wherever you want and rename it to wildfly (for easier use)

2) Download KIE Workbench and KIE Server distributions specific for Wildfly from repo1.maven.org

Workbench: kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.3.0.Final-wildfly8.war

Server: kie-server-6.3.0.Final-ee7.war

```
Rename the workbench file to "kie-wb" and the server file to "kie-server" for easier use.
Copy both files to "wildfly\standalone\deployments" folder.
```

3) Set up environment variables JAVA_HOME to JDK 1.8 jar and WILDFLY_HOME to wildfly folder.

4) Open the cmd and change directory to the "wildfly/bin" folder.
   Run the command: add-user.bat and select b (application users)
   Create following users:
    for server
        name: kieserver 
        password: kieserver1!
        roles: kie-server
    for workbench
        name: workbench 
        password: workbench1!
        roles: admin, kie-server

5) Run the server with command:

```
   standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full.xml 
-Dorg.kie.server.id=wildfly-kieserver 
-Dorg.kie.server.location=http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server 
-Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://localhost:8080/kie-wb/rest/controller
```

6) Enter the workbench with the appropriate user and pass on the following URL: `http://localhost:8080/kie-wb`